# Python, Adding 3rd and 4th rows of a CSV file together

Tags: python, csv

Brand new to Python, and not a programmer by any means, sorry for the very Newbie question.

I have a CSV file and I need to add the 3rd and 4th rows together for every column, and the best option would be to have the results output to a new file.

I realize this isn't a hard problem, but jumping into this for the first time is a bit overwhelming.

I've search for an example program to graft from, but nothing was forth coming.

Thank you very much for any help you could provide.

Comment: What does "add the 3rd and 4th rows together for every column" mean? You want to sum across the 3rd and 4th rows and get 2 sums? You want a single sum of all the values in the 3rd and 4th rows? Something else? Please provide some sample input (a few lines of a csv that is representative of what you're working with). Also some sample output, what type of data do you expect to have after performing this computation?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

Take this as example.csv:

```
column1,column2,column3
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
8,7,6
```

```
CSV_filename = 'example.csv'
total_columns = 3

results = []

import csv

with open(CSV_filename) as csv_file:
    temp = []
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            line_count += 1
        elif line_count == 3:
            for i in range(total_columns):
                temp.append(row[i])
            line_count += 1
        elif line_count == 4:
            for i in range(total_columns):
                temp_eq = temp[i]
                final_prep = int(temp_eq) + int(row[i])
                results.append(final_prep)
            line_count += 1
        else:
            line_count += 1
print(results)
```